# Trying to clip edges from UIImage to fit to ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have added an icon to my assets to be used in an image view. However, When I put it in an image view the outer edges seem to be larger than the image itself. Is there any way I can fully fill the image. Even when I try scale to fill or aspect fill, fit options still there remains a margin in between.

In other words I want my circular image to be tangent to the image view rectangle

[The example of what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGE1G.png)

Comment: Are you sure your image has no margins at all? Sounds like the aspect is working, but the image itself has margins.

Comment: is there a way to remove these margins programmatically or should I redesign the image according to some specifications

Comment: you could change the frame of the imageView as you like and set contentType to .center, then it should work...

Comment: Yes but I want my imageView to keep its frame.

Comment: If your image has those white margins and you don't want to mess with the imageView's frame, cropping the image seems like the smart move here.